# WPML Header Dropdown menu issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

could you please tell me why i see this in this WPML language switcher menu ? 
https://s1.postimg.org/3szc6f1kkf/My_Blog_My_Word_Press_Blog.png

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: here is the site url: http://ndscript.com/sece/,if you want then i can post header.php file

Answer (score -2):

I suppose there is somewhere an unclosed HTML tag (without `>` symbol) in your header code.

Comment: I found this in your code `<span data-hover="<img class="wpml-ls-flag" src="http://ndscript.com/sece/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/flags/en.png" alt="en" title="ENG"><span class="wpml-ls-display">ENG</span>">` As you can see the IMG tag inserts in HTML attribute which is not correct.

Comment: how i fix this?